# Using Squid as proxy for allowing LimaCharlie Sensor to talk to LimaCharlie cloud

Tags: proxy, squid

I am configuring LimaCharlie sensor on  Windows 2022 server that does not have Internet access.

The LimaCharlie sensor is a software that  is installed on computers, and  uses HTTPS tcp/443 to communicate with the LimaCharlie.io cloud.

**Architecture of the LimaCharlie Sensor:**
[image]

**Endpoints**

Endpoints used by LimaCharlie sensor:

- b76093c3662d5b4f.lc.limacharlie.io:443 - Pinned SSL certificates (SSL interception unsupported)
- b76093c3662d5b4f.edr.limacharlie.io:443 - Non-Pinned SSL certificates (SSL interception supported)
- b76093c3662d5b4f.wss.limacharlie.io:443
- b76093c3662d5b4f.ingest.limacharlie.io:443

**Proxy**

To get data to LimaCharlie, I have Windows 2022 Server and installed Squid proxy (Console App Squid for Windows) on from https://squid.diladele.com.

I have not done anything to the configuration (it is default).

The proxy server is called "vm-proxy" and the client is called "vm-client".

**Architecture of the proxy setup**
[image]

**Client setup of proxy variable**

On the client I have done the following:

Set System Environment variable `LC_PROXY` to the value `-`.

Created a registry key in `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`:

- Type: string
- Name: ProxyServer
- Value: vm-proxy:3128

On the client I can get Internet via the proxy server, and I can also ping the proxy server.

```
ping vm-proxy

Pinging vm-proxy.awdawd3rwr.adadwawd.internal.cloudapp.net [10.0.0.4] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.0.0.4: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.0.0.4: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.0.0.4: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.0.0.4: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 10.0.0.4:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 2ms, Average = 1ms
```

**Client installation of LimaCharlie**

To install LimaCharlie I opened CMD as administrator and did the following command:

```
hcp_win_x64_release_4.29.0.msi InstallationKey=AAAAB...oUECAwEAAQ== LC_PROXY=vm-proxy:3128
```

**Error message from LimaCharlie Sensor on the client**

```
TS 1710860518: hcp launched
TS 1710860518: bootstrap used
TS 1710860518: conn started
TS 1710860519: using proxy
TS 1710860519: proxy env:
TS 1710860519: vm-proxy:3128TS 1710860519: 
TS 1710860519: connecting
TS 1710860519: tls error:
TS 1710860519: SSL - An invalid SSL record was receivedTS 1710860519: 
TS 1710860519: tls error:
TS 1710860519: SSL - An invalid SSL record was receivedTS 1710860519: 
TS 1710860519: disconnecting from no send headers
```

Comment: just allow on the firewall the native connection to one target, limited to 80,443 it is not at all bad - but if this machines is not allowed to communicate to the internet, then these sensors are not on the correct machine, or as i guess the wrong product has been used, or wrong interpreted howto use it.

Comment: While for Plain http requests no Certificate is required, you only could install the SSL Certificate on the Client which is used on the proxy to intercept these connection allow via port redirect the access. but in my mind, it is still the wrong way to solve this issue.

Comment: djdomi: How can I do this?

Comment: There needs to be more than "TLS Error". If the product doesn't have more verbose logging, open a support ticket with the vendor. Even better, perform a correlated network packet capture on the Windows Server and the proxy server.

Comment: *I have not done anything to the configuration (it is default).* Don't install complex software and assume it does what you want without telling it what you want! Configure squid, and check the logs to see what happens!

Comment: "I am becoming increasingly convinced that the person we are communicating with is not a Business Administrator in a Business Environment. Could you please ask the responsible person for the network on your business premises to either allow or implement this solution? This person can create and allow access for this specific domain on port 443 IMHO."

Comment: djdomi: This is my Azure cloud development tenant. I am the network administrator.